# Hashicorp vault hvac client doesnt read secret, always prints "None"

Tags: python-3.5, hashicorp-vault

I would like to read a secret from vault, below is the script I am using:

```
    import os
    import hvac
    client = hvac.Client(url='http://127.0.0.1:8200', token=os.environ['VAULT_TOKEN'] )
    print(client.is_authenticated())
    print(client.list_token_roles())
    print(client.read('secret/foo'))
```

It prints 'True' for is_authenticated and it even lists the policies, however prints "None" for the read secret. I suspected policies and capabilities, so I added "read" capability to my config file, but still doesn't work.

What could be wrong?

Below is my config.hcl

```
    disable_mlock = true
    ui            = false
    
    listener "tcp" {
      address     = "127.0.0.1:8200"
      tls_disable = "true"
    }
    
    storage "file" {
      path = "/home/user1/bin/vault-data"
    }
    
    path "secret/*" {
      capabilities = ["read"]
    }
```

some how a very old version of hvac is still in use and I have to stick to it, can not update/upgrade it.

Below are the versions:

- hvac version = 0.2.17
- vault = v1.6.0
- Python = 3.5.2

Comment: Secrets engine is kv1 or kv2?

Comment: @MattSchuchard it could be kv1 coz i have not upgraded it to kv2. sorry but i couldnt figure out how to get version of secrets engine, all i see is how to upgrade it. Thanks for your reply, could you let me know if there is a way